# Change button markup of searching form

Tags: theming, forms

I am trying to find a way out about five hours now, i have studied and tried a lot of different things but i couldn't find the right drupal way to do what i want... Please help with the following.

I have the search-block-form which displays a search input text field and a button. The markup for the button **now** is the following (produced by drupal core):

```
<button class="form-submit" id="edit-submit--2" name="op" value="Search" type="submit">Search</button>
```

I want to add extra markup **inside the `<button></button>`**, like the following:

```
<button class="form-submit" id="edit-submit--2" name="op" value="" type="submit"><i class="fi-magnifying-glass"></i></button>
```

I know of course how to set the value=' ' and i have to say that i've already tried #prefix and #suffix parameters. I don't want to add markup prior to the button element or after that. I should put markup inside, between the element's tags.
I tried also change the hook *theme_button($variables)* but my problem is that i want to change **only** the button for search-block-form and not all the button elements.

As some of you have already understand, i use foundation 5 framework and i want to make the search button like this:

[image: search-bar example screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*** Updated ***

You can do this by overriding theme_button() in your theme. Note that the code here is copied from theme_button(), with the return value adjusted accordingly:

```
function THEMENAME_button($variables)
{
  $element = $variables['element'];
  $element['#attributes']['type'] = 'submit';
  element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name', 'value'));

  $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-' . $element['#button_type'];
  if (!empty($element['#attributes']['disabled']))
  {
    $element['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-button-disabled';
  }

  if(isset($element['#search_button']) && $element['#search_button'])
  {
    return '<button' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . '><i class="fi-magnifying-glass"></i></button>';
  }
  else
  {
    return '<input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' />';
  }
}
```

Then you need to add #search_button = TRUE to the button in hook_form_alter()

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
  if($form_id == 'MYFORMID')
  {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#search_button'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Note: This will render the button as requested. No guarantees that it will actually work with the Form API. That needs separate testing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but no. It's all about security. The #value is just plain text.

Comment: I just did some testing - this can't be done. Browsers render the value attribute as plain text, so there isn't anything you can do in Drupal that would get around that. It's a browser limitation not a Drupal limitation.

Comment: @Jaypan I think you might have misunderstood...the OP is trying to get some extra markup into a FAPI submit button (not input); browsers are happy to render the markup inside a `<button>`, even of type submit, but it's not necessarily obvious how to get Drupal to play along, especially if you only want to target the one element. You're right that `value` _attributes_ are rendered as plain text, but FAPI `#value`s are a different thing. This is something that just needs to be attacked at the theme level

Comment: You're right, I did misunderstand. I updated my post with a solution.

Comment: Good approach, in case OP is using a sub-theme of [Foundation](https://www.drupal.org/project/zurb_foundation) the code should be copied from `zurb_foundation_button` instead to make sure everything stays consistent

Comment: Yes, @Jaypan, this seems to work. I am still testing the rest Form API but it seems no problem.

Comment: @Clive, you said _OP_. What does this mean ?

Comment: OP = Original Poster (you)